# The virtual machine does not accept mouse and keyboard input in the authentication dialog

Tags: 22.04, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I am running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on VMware 17.5, hosted on Windows 11. After long inactivity, when returning to Ubuntu machine I have autentification screen where I must enter password. But looks like I can't input from keyboard anything and it not accepts any mouse clicking. How to fix that?

Comment: If you have SSH set up, you can try using `loginctl` then `loginctl unlock-session <id>` as a workaround